# Cypress: check if new opened tab has correct URL

Tags: cypress

If I have a link in my website. Eg. `<a href="//google.com" target="_blank">go to Google</a>` and I want to make a test:

- GIVEN link (html tag `a`)
- WHEN click the link
- THEN browser opens new tab and URL of this tab includes 'google.com'

I know that this **does not work**:

```js
cy.get('a').click();
cy.url().should('include', 'google.com');
```

Answer (score 8):

Since the `a` has a `target` attribute you can do this.

```
cy.get('a')
  .should('be.visible')
  .then(($a) => {
     expect($a).to.have.attr('target','_blank')
     // update attr to open in same tab
     $a.attr('target', '_self')
  })
  .click()
cy.url().should('include', 'google.com')
```

Depending on your app and what you are wanting to test, using `cy.request()` and checking on 200 status code may suffice for an external url.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `removeAttr` to remove target and then click the link and assert. Something like:

```js
cy.get('a').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
cy.url().should('include', 'google.com')
```

Comment: That is a really interesting approach. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that this kind of practice of removing the target could have side effects. Such as in an onClick event looking at the target. It will also make it confusing for any developer executing the test from cypress UI as they will see a link without the expected target attribute.